# SSH private key auth on Windows 10 Bash

Tags: windows-10, bash, ssh

i have some Linux installed on by Laptop and use SSH with private key authentication to connect to a server. Recently, I installed Win10 with the bash developer extension on by desktop. Since I only have one user account on this server, and hence only on key, i simply moved by private key file into the respective directory of my windows bash.

However, whenever I open a new bash instance and try to connect to the server, the error message: 'Permission denied (publickey).' is returned. 
My current fix are the following steps: exec ssh-agent bash; ssh-add;

While I could obviously add this into .profile, I would be required to enter the passphrase whenever I open bash.

Does anyone has some suggestions how to fix this more properly, s.t. I only have to enter my passphrase whenever I connect to the server and that I do not have to reinitialize my ssh key in every bash session.

kind regards

Comment: My understanding is that the type of authentication that the beta feature supports is limited.  Are you sure your key is supported?

Comment: how can i check whether the type is supported? However, by manually starting the ssh-agent, everything works more or less as expected...

Comment: @hansal **See: [ssh(1)](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh).**  You can use `ssh -Q` followed by one of the following: `cipher` | `cipher-auth` | `mac` | `kex` | `key` | `key-cert` | `key-plain` | `protocol-version`

Answer (score 0):

Keys must only be accessible to the user they're intended for and no other account, service, or group.

- I don't use WSL, as it's a security nightmare, creating more problems than it solves, so I'll provide both ways to set correct permissions

---

---

### Windows Powershell Terminal

---

- **GUI:**

  - ***[File] Properties - Security - Advanced***

    1. Set ***Owner*** to the key's user
    2. Remove all users, groups, and services, *except for the key's user*, under ***Permission Entries***
    3. Set key's user to ***Full Control***

- **CLI:**

  ```powershell
  :: Set Variable ::
  set key="C:\Path\to\key"

  :: Remove Inheritance ::
  cmd /c icacls %key% /c /t /inheritance:d

  :: Set Ownership to Owner ::
  cmd /c icacls %key% /c /t /grant %username%:F

  :: Remove All Users, except for Owner ::
  cmd /c icacls %key%  /c /t /remove Administrator BUILTIN\Administrators BUILTIN Everyone System Users

  :: Verify ::
  cmd /c icacls %key%
  ```

---

---

### WSL Bash Terminal

---

- **CLI**

  ```bash
  # Set Variables

    # Key  
      key="/path/to/key"

    # User:
      user="$(echo $USER)"

  # Set Ownership
    # This assumes user's name is also user's group name
      chown $user:$user $key

  # Set Access Rights
    chmod 0600 $key

  # Verify
  ls -l $key
  ```